# PDF to Image Conversion - PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

Note: PDF files would be uploaded by user.

I am making a document sharing website(pdf). I don't want users to be able to copy/select the pdf file text. I am looking for a nice PDF/Image Document viewer. Currently using the following method:

I am using imagemagick to convert PDF file to Jpeg. But the process is too slow even after disabling OpenMP. I was looking forward to convert full PDF to different image files but decided to just convert the first image to a thumbnail because the process is so slow.

I am using it on my local machine and it takes more than 30 seconds to convert 40-50 pages in good quality. So if there are pdf files more than 100 pages, this process would ruin the user experience.

Is there any way to convert PDF to Image files?

Also is there a way to let this process (pdf to image) happen asynchronously? Like the user filling out file details while the pdf is being uploaded and converted, something like YT videos?

Comment: Do you want us to make the code for you?

Comment: why did you disable openmp?

Comment: @rostok - I read that if openmp was enabled, the process would slow down drastically.

Comment: isn't this easy ? https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFLib

Comment: Use PHPGhostscript [https://github.com/DaanDeSmedt/PHPGhostscript]

Answer (score 0):

Enter the command in `exec()` function, this will help you out

```
<?php
    $pdf_url = 'testfile.pdf'; // Url of the PDF
    $image_name = 'output.jpg'; // Set the image name

    exec('convert "'.$pdf_url.'" -colorspace RGB -resize 800 "'.$image_name.'"', $output, $return_var);

?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

¿You use a linux sever?

Just use convert command and put [0] sufix to pdf file for save a cover:

```
exec("convert '/home/sample.pdf[0]' '/home/test.png'");
```